# How to get current translated language in edge browser

Tags: translate

I'm able to get current translated language in chrome but not able to get the translated language in edge. I want to know the current translated language in edge browser. but the lang attribute is not changing in edge browser.

I tried all forums

```
document.querySelector('[lang]').attributes.lang.value.toString()
```